# Do unused structs affect the bytecode?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Suppose that you have a contract like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Foo {
  struct UnusedStruct {
    uint256 unusedProperty;
  }

  function someFunction(uint256 foo) external pure {
    foo;
  }
}
```

Does the unused struct affect the compiler output in any way? Would the bytecode be an exact match if I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original Answer

It looks like the answer is **yes**. Unused structs affect the bytecode, with or without the optimizer enabled.

I compiled the contract in my OP with Solidity 0.7.4 and got this bytecode:

```
6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b5060828061001e6000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c80637062c09414602d575b600080fd5b604760048036036020811015604157600080fd5b50356049565b005b5056fea2646970667358221220c463e13176639d4ae660803fd6f458ac7418543bd3e51424009be8229d237f9964736f6c63430007040033
```

Whereas without the struct, I got this:

```
6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b5060828061001e6000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c80637062c09414602d575b600080fd5b604760048036036020811015604157600080fd5b50356049565b005b5056fea26469706673582212204d61c9126d1dcd65178031ed2b21287fa510042623746631fc6f9e0b95a95ffc64736f6c63430007040033
```

In both cases I enabled the optimizer with 200 runs.

#### Update

As per @goodvibration's feedback, it's important to note that while the bytecodes are different, the contracts are functionally the same.

That is, the only thing that is different is the 32 bytes that appears before the last 11 bytes of a contract bytecode. This is the hash of the [contract metadata](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.4/metadata.html).

Comment: I'd highly expect the answer to be No, so may I suggest checking that again?

Comment: @goodvibration I verified Paul's result. Also, Paul, the text in the middle of your answer should read "Whereas without the struct..." instead of "Whereas without the bytecode...".

Comment: @ShaneFontaine: Not precisely, see my answer below.

Comment: I did not say anything about the ABIs (which are actually **identical**, not different). My answer is with regards to the bytecode strings.

Answer (score 3):

Following the answer by @Paul Razvan Berg, I would like to add that the two bytecodes in that answer are essentially identical in terms of functionality.

Specifically, the only difference are the 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters) which appear right before the last 11 bytes (22 hexadecimal characters) in each bytecode.

These 32 bytes consist of the contract's metadata, which is just a hash of the contract source code (and possibly a few other things like its absolute path on your machine, etc).

This metadata has no impact on the functionality of the contract of course.

Note that prior to solc 0.5.x, the metadata used to be the 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters) which appear right before the last 2 bytes (4 hexadecimal characters).